# Mono 5 on Solaris Build issues

Tags: mono, solaris

I am trying to build Mono on Solaris 10 and have ran into an issue with error "Posix system lacks support for recursive mutexes". I am trying to build this with gcc 3.4.3 and I have installed gmake, gar, granlib, and gstrip to replace their Solaris alternatives. I have found a possible solution, but I can not locate the blog that references this line "1) patch /usr/lib/pkgconfig/gthread-2.0.pc to replace the -mt option (see Jonel's blog)" located at https://lists.dot.net/pipermail/mono-list/2007-January/034101.html. The blog is no longer active. Does anyone have any ideas what the patch they are referring to may be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The wayback machine has a copy of the blog. https://web.archive.org/web/20080827164206/http://blogs.rientongroup.com/jonel/2005/04/solaris-10-x86-and-mono.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 10 does support recursive mutexes.

Per [the Solaris 10 `pthread_mutexattr_settype` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5168/pthread-mutexattr-settype-3c.html#scrolltoc):

> **PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE**
>
> A thread attempting to relock this mutex without first unlocking it
>   will succeed in locking the mutex. The relocking deadlock that can
>   occur with mutexes of type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` cannot occur with
>   this type of mutex. Multiple locks of this mutex require the same
>   number of unlocks to release the mutex before another thread can
>   acquire the mutex. A thread attempting to unlock a mutex that another
>   thread has locked will return with an error. A thread attempting to
>   unlock an unlocked mutex will return with an error. This type of mutex
>   is only supported for mutexes whose process shared attribute is
>   `PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE`.

Also per the man page, the required compile/link options, and the proper `#include` statement:

```
cc –mt [ flag... ] file... –lpthread [ library... ]
#include <pthread.h>
```

Note the addition of `-lpthread`.  I suspect the blog you're referring to said to replace `-mt` with `-mt -lpthread`.

Answer (score 0):

(A bit more research into this problem, prodded by the Unix question [**How to install .net Mono on Solaris 11 (source code compile)?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507655/how-to-install-net-mono-on-solaris-11-source-code-compile) produced [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507937/111943), which I'm repeating here.)

The exact value that you set `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to doesn't matter.  Mono is incorrectly defining the `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` macro:

```
case "${host}" in
        *solaris* )
                AC_MSG_CHECKING(for Solaris XPG4 support)
                if test -f /usr/lib/libxnet.so; then
                        CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600"
                        CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -D__EXTENSIONS__"
                        CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1" <-- WRONG
                        LIBS="$LIBS -lxnet"
```

The `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` macro does not exist in either [the POSIX 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html) or [the POSIX 7 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/V2_chap02.html).

Even Linux agrees that `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` should not be defined here.  Per [the Linux `feature_test_macros` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html):

> **_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED**
>
> If this macro is defined, and `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is defined, then expose definitions corresponding to the XPG4v2 (SUSv1) UNIX    extensions (UNIX 95).  Defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` with a value of 500 or more also produces the same effect as defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`.  Use of `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` in new  source code should be avoided.
>
> Since defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` with a value of 500 or more has the same effect as defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`, the latter (obsolete) feature test macro is generally not described in the SYNOPSIS in man pages.

Note the precise wording:

**If this macro (`_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`) is defined, and `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is defined, then expose definitions corresponding to the XPG4v2  (SUSv1) UNIX extensions (UNIX 95). ...**

Defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` *to any value* while also defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` results in XPG4v2, and that's **NOT** the XPG6 necessary to get recursive mutexes.

You're likely running into [this check in the Solaris 11 `/usr/include/sys/feature_tests.h`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/feature_tests.h?r=2b6e762c557496a41438c0b105d604f60c593682#345):

```
/*
 * It is invalid to compile an XPG3, XPG4, XPG4v2, or XPG5 application
 * using c99.  The same is true for POSIX.1-1990, POSIX.2-1992, POSIX.1b,
 * and POSIX.1c applications. Likewise, it is invalid to compile an XPG6
 * or a POSIX.1-2001 application with anything other than a c99 or later
 * compiler.  Therefore, we force an error in both cases.
 */
#if defined(_STDC_C99) && (defined(__XOPEN_OR_POSIX) && !defined(_XPG6))
#error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications \
 and pre-2001 POSIX applications"
#elif !defined(_STDC_C99) && \
 (defined(__XOPEN_OR_POSIX) && defined(_XPG6))
#error "Compiler or options invalid; UNIX 03 and POSIX.1-2001 applications \
 require the use of c99"
#endif
```

`_XPG6` gets defined [earlier in the file, in this block](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/feature_tests.h?r=2b6e762c557496a41438c0b105d604f60c593682#216):

```
/*
 * Use of _XOPEN_SOURCE
 *
 * The following X/Open specifications are supported:
 *
 * X/Open Portability Guide, Issue 3 (XPG3)
 * X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 4 (XPG4)
 * X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 4, Version 2 (XPG4v2)
 * X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 5 (XPG5)
 * Open Group Technical Standard, Issue 6 (XPG6), also referred to as
 *    IEEE Std. 1003.1-2001 and ISO/IEC 9945:2002.
 *
 * XPG4v2 is also referred to as UNIX 95 (SUS or SUSv1).
 * XPG5 is also referred to as UNIX 98 or the Single Unix Specification,
 *     Version 2 (SUSv2)
 * XPG6 is the result of a merge of the X/Open and POSIX specifications
 *     and as such is also referred to as IEEE Std. 1003.1-2001 in
 *     addition to UNIX 03 and SUSv3.
 *
 * When writing a conforming X/Open application, as per the specification
 * requirements, the appropriate feature test macros must be defined at
 * compile time. These are as follows. For more info, see standards(5).
 *
 * Feature Test Macro                    Specification
 * ------------------------------------------------  -------------
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE                                         XPG3
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_VERSION = 4                   XPG4
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED = 1           XPG4v2
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE = 500                                   XPG5
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE = 600  (or POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L)      XPG6
 *
 * In order to simplify the guards within the headers, the following
 * implementation private test macros have been created. Applications
 * must NOT use these private test macros as unexpected results will
 * occur.
 *
 * Note that in general, the use of these private macros is cumulative.
 * For example, the use of _XPG3 with no other restrictions on the X/Open
 * namespace will make the symbols visible for XPG3 through XPG6
 * compilation environments. The use of _XPG4_2 with no other X/Open
 * namespace restrictions indicates that the symbols were introduced in
 * XPG4v2 and are therefore visible for XPG4v2 through XPG6 compilation
 * environments, but not for XPG3 or XPG4 compilation environments.
 *
 * _XPG3    X/Open Portability Guide, Issue 3 (XPG3)
 * _XPG4    X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 4 (XPG4)
 * _XPG4_2  X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 4, Version 2 (XPG4v2/UNIX 95/SUS)
 * _XPG5    X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 5 (XPG5/UNIX 98/SUSv2)
 * _XPG6    Open Group Technical Standard, Issue 6 (XPG6/UNIX 03/SUSv3)
 */

/* X/Open Portability Guide, Issue 3 */
#if defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && (_XOPEN_SOURCE - 0 < 500) && \
    (_XOPEN_VERSION - 0 < 4) && !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED)
#define _XPG3
/* X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 4 */
#elif   (defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && _XOPEN_VERSION - 0 == 4)
#define _XPG4
#define _XPG3
/* X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 4, Version 2 */
#elif (defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED - 0 == 1)
#define _XPG4_2
#define _XPG4
#define _XPG3
/* X/Open CAE Specification, Issue 5 */
#elif   (_XOPEN_SOURCE - 0 == 500)
#define _XPG5
#define _XPG4_2
#define _XPG4
#define _XPG3
#undef  _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE         199506L
/* Open Group Technical Standard , Issue 6 */
#elif   (_XOPEN_SOURCE - 0 == 600) || (_POSIX_C_SOURCE - 0 == 200112L)
#define _XPG6
#define _XPG5
#define _XPG4_2
#define _XPG4
#define _XPG3
#undef  _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE         200112L
#undef  _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE           600
#endif
```